# libaums threw IOException: unsupported PeripheralQualifier or PeripheralDeviceType

Tags: java, android, usb-otg, scsi

#### Problem

Hi, I'm facing a problem with my disk driver enclosure.
When plugged in and initialized my device object, it threw an IOException as the title above.
The message right before the exception is this:

```
D/ScsiBlockDevice: inquiry response: ScsiInquiryResponse [peripheralQualifier=0, peripheralDeviceType=13, removableMedia=false, spcVersion=6, responseDataFormat=2]
```

Then I checked what the device type was. I'm not 100% sure but I found that device type `0x0D` indicated `enclosure services device`. I thought there was something to do with my device because it is truly a disk driver enclosure with SSD in it. So I'm asking do we support this kind of device? Or whether I can do something to make this work properly.

#### Expected behavior

The device initializes successfully.

#### Actual behavior

The device cannot be initialized

##### Stacktrace

```
D/PartitionTableFactory: FileSystemPartitionTableCreator returned null
D/GPT: EFI test string EFI PART
D/GPT: EFI test string matches!
D/PartitionTableFactory: Found partition table GPTCreator
W/.moonplayer_gvr: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method boolean libcore.io.Linux.access(java.lang.String, int)
W/.moonplayer_gvr: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method boolean libcore.io.Linux.access(java.lang.String, int)
W/System.err: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (me.jahnen.libaums.core.fs.ntfs.NTFSStructure).
W/System.err: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
D/ScsiBlockDevice: inquiry response: ScsiInquiryResponse [peripheralQualifier=0, peripheralDeviceType=13, removableMedia=false, spcVersion=6, responseDataFormat=2]
```

#### Code where problem occurs

```java
UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this.mContext);
for(UsbMassStorageDevice device : devices) {
    try {
        device.init();
    } catch(IllegalStateException | IOException  e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```